# Match in awk disregarding white space

Tags: bash, awk

```
 1 #!/bin/bash
 2 KEY_FILE="keys"
 3 TABLE_FILE="table" #pipe delimited data
 4 
 5 i=0;
 6 while read key #print out rows in table file with key in keys file
 7 do
 8   let i=i+1
 9   # key is first column in table
10   # print status to stderr
11   (echo "$KEY_FILE : line $i" >&2)
12   awk -F '|' "\$1 == $key {print \$0}" $TABLE_FILE
13 done < $KEY_FILE
14
```

From line 12, will awk match the first column against the key if there is a white space discrepancy?

Comment: You may be able to use the `join` utility if your files are sorted (they can be sorted on the fly) and it doesn't matter if the output may be in a different order than the input.

Comment: yes! Thanks for seeing through my question and making me aware of yet another great Unix utility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because you set your field separator. Whitespace characters are now significant.

You can set your field separator to be a regular expression to slurp up whitespace.  Also, pass the value of the shell variable into an awk variable to avoid quoting hell.

```
gawk --posix -F '[[:space:]]*\|[[:space:]]*' -v k=$key '$1 == k' $TABLE_FILE
```

Note that `{print $0}` is the default action, so that can be omitted.

Also, awk can handle two files, so you don't need the bash loop:

```
gawk --posix -F '[[:space:]]*\|[[:space:]]*' '
  NR == FNR {key[$1] = ""; next}
  ($1 in key)
' $KEY_FILE $TABLE_FILE
```

The expression `NR == FNR` means that awk is looking at the first file in the list of files (NR is the "total record number" and FNR is the record number of the current file: they will only be the same for the first file). This program saves the keys in the `key` array, and the prints the records in the table file that have a key in that array.

Comment: Thanks for the great response, you answered my original question, but now I'm curious about your clearly superior solution. Though it doens't quite work for me (it's not printing any matches).

Comment: @mkirk, show us a sample of your files in the question please.